# Using Batch Processing Document AI inside the google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, ocr, batch-processing, cloud-document-ai

I have a scenario where I am uploading a local file to a Cloud Storage bucket, triggering a Cloud Function (xyz). Within this Cloud Function, I am performing a batch processing task using Google Cloud Document AI. The challenge I am facing is that the batch processing might take longer than the execution time allowed for the Cloud Function, leading to timeouts.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
from typing import Optional
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai

def batch_process_documents(
    gcs_input_uri: str,
):
    project_id = "tally-ai-394207"
    location = "us"
    processor_id = "d5efc50f9221c006"  # invoice parser
    gcs_output_uri = "gs://document-ai-output-bucket-haritha/ManishoOutput/"  # Must end with a '/'
    
    # Set the API endpoint based on the location
    api_endpoint = f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com"
    client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=api_endpoint)
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

    # Specify a GCS URI Prefix to process an entire directory
    gcs_prefix = documentai.GcsPrefix(gcs_uri_prefix=gcs_input_uri)
    input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_prefix=gcs_prefix)

    # Cloud Storage URI for the Output Directory
    gcs_output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig.GcsOutputConfig(
        gcs_uri=gcs_output_uri
    )

    # Where to write results
    output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig(gcs_output_config=gcs_output_config)

    name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    request = documentai.BatchProcessRequest(
        name=name,
        input_documents=input_config,
        document_output_config=output_config,
    )

    # BatchProcess returns a Long Running Operation (LRO)
    operation = client.batch_process_documents(request)

    # Wait for the operation to complete
    operation.result()
    
    # NOTE: Can also use callbacks for asynchronous processing
    #
    # def my_callback(future):
    #   result = future.result()
    #
    # operation.add_done_callback(my_callback)
```

I would like to trigger another Cloud Function (abc) upon completion of the batch processing or can we pass the cloud fuction(abc) instead of my_callback  and a way to inform the cloud function(abc) that the processing has been completed. Additionally, I need to pass information returned by batch_process_documents to abc. Given the potential timeout issue, I'm looking for a solution to handle this situation more effectively.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

I've implemented a solution where I upload a local file to a Cloud Storage bucket, triggering a Cloud Function (xyz). Inside this Cloud Function, I'm utilizing Google Cloud Document AI to perform batch processing. To handle the asynchronous nature of batch processing, I considered using a callback function (my_callback), but I am concerned about potential timeouts since the batch processing task might exceed the allowed execution time of Cloud Function (xyz).

What were you expecting:

From a design perspective, I anticipated that the Cloud Function (xyz) might time out before the batch processing completes its execution. I am exploring alternative design options to ensure that the batch processing task can complete successfully, and I am particularly interested in triggering another Cloud Function (abc) upon the completion of batch processing. Additionally, I am looking for a way to pass information returned by batch_process_documents to abc in this scenario.

Comment: If you are processing a small quantity of files, can't you use the online processing option? This way you don't need to wait upon completion, and can even distribute processing over many cloud functions. Im supposing you're attached to the cloud functions option.

Comment: I want to use asynchronous approach only.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is the following:

1. Start batch process
2. Trigger cloud function
3. Cloud function call DocumentAI API and check status of operation
4. If not done, create a GCP Cloud Task to trigger the step 3 cloud function with some delay.
5. This loop will run until completion.
6. Once the step 3 cloud function sees that the operation is finished, trigger your desired cloud function.

Other possible solution for the future is:
If GCP eventarc creates an event type that is sent once the batch processing is done, you could use that with your desired cloud function